# What is the single tile trash can trick in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

> **Related:**
>   [How do I collect rocks in Dwarf Fortress](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1259/how-do-i-collect-rocks-in-dwarf-fortress)

I've heard of a technique for dealing with the large amounts of stone is something about a single tile being a trash can for everything.  How does this work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You designate a garbage dump zone in only one tile using <kbd>i</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd>.

Then you give the order to <kbd>d</kbd>ump the stones you want to dump, or use mass dump: <kbd>d</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>. They will all be stored and forbidden on that one tile. To use them you'll have to un<kbd>f</kbd>orbid them or use mass reclaim: <kbd>d</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: It is worth noting that some view this as an exploit/bug and it may be changed in future versions.

Comment: True, but it's a single-player game, so who cares what other people think. ;-)

Comment: @user56 maybe multiplayer will be possible in future releases